# Query reference error with test code and class

Tags: unit-test

I have the following test code which is producing this error when run :

Error :

```
SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Organization_Model__c.Org_Model_BP__c
```

I don't understand why I am getting that error for my references to the Org_Model_BP__c field, but I am not getting it for the Org_Model_CSH__c. If I simply replace my references to Org_Model_BP__c with Org_Model_CSH__c I no longer get an error. I am populating those fields equally in the test code and am referencing them in the same way in the working class. It's very odd to me. Both fields are simple lookup fields. The only difference is their name.

Test code :

```
@isTest
private class TestCSHOrgModelQuarterly {
        static Id getRecordTypeId(String sObjectType, String Name) {
        return [select id from recordtype where sobjecttype=:sObjectType and name=:Name limit 1].id;
    }
        static final Id Org_Rectype = getRecordTypeId('Organization_Model__c','Global');
        static final Id A_MM_Rectype = getRecordTypeId('Account','Parent');

        User User1;
        Account Acc1;
        Organization_Model__c Org1;

        String u;  // Unique number for this test run.

        TestCSHOrgModelQuarterly() {

            // Create a unique string for this test so we're never confused with existing data.
            u = Datetime.now().millisecond().format();
            // Create the two users:
            Profile p = [select id from profile where name='Standard User'];

            User1 = new User(LastName=u+'Test2', email='test2@vbart.com', CompanyName='Testing', Country='USA', Department='Sales', Title='Tester 2', alias='vbartest',
            username='test2@vbart.com', emailencodingkey='UTF-8', languagelocalekey='en_US', localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p.Id, timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles',Division='North America', isActive = True);
            insert User1;

            Acc1 = new Account(Name=u+'Test1', recordtypeid=A_MM_Rectype, status_corporate_travel__c = 'Client', ownerid=UserInfo.getUserId(), billingcountry='USA');
            insert Acc1;  

            Org1 = new Organization_Model__c(Name=u+'Test2', recordtypeid=Org_Rectype, Org_Model_CSH__c = UserInfo.getUserId(),Org_Model_BP__c = User1.id, Account__c = Acc1.id, Org_Model_CSH_c = 'Quarterly');
            insert Org1;            
            }

        static testMethod void testReview() {
        // Reduce the number of message we get during debugging.
        system.debug(Logginglevel.DEBUG);

        // All we're really doing is setting up the data, calling the routine, and checking the results.
        TestCSHOrgModelQuarterly x = new TestCSHOrgModelQuarterly();

        Date tod = Date.Today();
        // Calculate the dates we might use for AM_Completion depending on record type.
        Date AM_Date_10 = Date.newInstance(tod.addMonths(1).year(),tod.addMonths(1).month(),10);
        Date AM_Date_15 = Date.newInstance(tod.addMonths(1).year(),tod.addMonths(1).month(),15);        

        test.startTest();
        CSHOrgModelQuarterly CSHR = new CSHOrgModelQuarterly();

        String xxx = CSHR.doReview(true);

        test.stopTest();

        // and Org1 should just have a new one.
        CSHNew__c Org1Csh = [select id, Due_Date__c from CSHNew__c where Organization_Model__c = :x.Org1.id ];
        system.assertEquals(AM_Date_10, Org1Csh.Due_Date__c);

         }
}
```

Here is the working class which the test is running against. If I replace my references to Org_Model_BP__c with Org_Model_CSH__c I no longer get the error when running the test.

```
public with sharing class CSHOrgModelQuarterly {

    public class CSH_and_Share_Pair {
        Client_Status_History_New__c csh;
        Client_Status_History_New__Share share;

        Id accountParent;
        Id accountOwnerId;
        Id accountParentOwnerId;
        String accountParentName;
        String accountParentOwnerUsername;
        String accountParentOwnerUsernameBP;


        CSH_and_Share_Pair(Organization_Model__c a, Client_Status_History_New__c csh) {
            this.accountParentName = a.Name;
            this.accountParentOwnerUsername = a.Org_Model_CSH__c;
            this.accountParentOwnerUsernameBP = a.Org_Model_BP__c;

            this.csh = csh;

            // So, if we have a non-null Org Model which has a different Org_Model_CSH than the Org_Model_BP, 
            // create a share, otherwise not.
            if ((a.Org_Model_BP__c != a.Org_Model_CSH__c)) {
                share = new Client_Status_History_New__Share(AccessLevel='Edit', UserOrGroupId= a.Org_Model_CSH__c);
            } else {
                share = null;
            }
        }
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't apparent from your code sample where that error is occurring. I'm guessing in the CSH_and_Share_Pair constructor where you call

```
this.accountParentOwnerUsername = a.Org_Model_BP__c;
```

If this is the case then you have passed in an instance of Organization_Model__c to this constructor where the Org_Model_BP__c column was never retrieved from the database.

You probably have something like this somewhere in your code.

```
List<Organization_Model__c> models = [Select Id, Org_Model_CSH__c from Organization_Model__c];
//...
new CSH_and_Share_Pair(models[0], blah);
```

The message

> SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Organization_Model__c.Org_Model_BP__c

is explicitly telling you that somewhere you pulled an Organization_Model__c record out of the database, but when you did you didn't pull the Org_Model_BP__c field that you are now trying to use.

You will need to hunt down that SOQL query and add the field to it. E.g.

```
List<Organization_Model__c> models = [Select Id, Org_Model_CSH__c , Org_Model_BP__c from Organization_Model__c];
```